# should i use unobtrusive javascript in asp mvc instead of writing my own validation code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-javascript, unobtrusive-validation

The javascript code for client validations is already written from scratch and is perfectly
working. But to make our solution more scalable and minimize lines we are thinking of replacing our Javascript client validations with the built in asp MVC support for unobtrusive javascript.
However there are scenarios where its particularly disadvantageous. E.g. I want to validate a field with regex. and the field isnt directly bound to the model. But to implement unobtrusive javascript I need to bind it to some field i am creating in the model just for the purpose of validation(and not using it in my form submit)
is there any way to achieve validation without binding a field to the model?
and what would be the considerable advantages if i replace the javascript code with unobtrusive validations even if not for all scenarios?

Comment: Go with asp.net mvc validation and use asp.net mvc client side framework to customise your validation process.

Answer (score 2):

Considerable advantages:

- Since unobstrusive validation is very well known by devs, your code is easier to understand by others (and by yourself in the future)
- Takes advantage of Html Helpers so validation attributes get added automatically. You write less code that is more readable.
- Your validation code is MUCH LESS error prone, since it's an open source project and people from all over the world pitch in to fix bugs and improve code performance.

Use unobstrusive for all models in the solution. If there's a validation that is not provided out of the box you can always [write up your own validation function](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301022/Creating-Custom-Validation-Attribute-in-MVC-3) for properties bound to your model.

Mind that there are many open source projects that expand the .net validator attributes, such as [MVC FoolProof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/)

Finally, if there are properties not bound to your model (wait, why are there properties not bound to your model?), you can write custom client-side code for those.

Comment: thanks for your answer. really helpful. I have another question. If I am using unobtrusive validation. What all bindings go with it using html helper. I know of html.editorfor and html.textboxfor. Can I have html.textbox? And I will definitely need to bind the field to the model if I am to use this validation right?

Comment: I believe that automatic data-val html attributes will only be added when you use EditorFor, TextboxFor, etc.

Comment: i am not able to add the data-val attributes using  textbox or textboxfor. Even if I add those attributes using Jquery, they get added but dont work. Let me clarify. On a page I have the code                 <input type="text" name="myname" id="myname" data-val="true" data-val-regex="This field must be numeric" data-val-regex-pattern="^\d+$" value=""/>
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="myname"></span>  If this is the thing I am coding directly into my html it works but not if this is generated by html helper and jquery(the exact same markup) why?